# difficulty pricing options using stochastic volatility

Tags: options, volatility, pricing, stochastic

can someone kindly explain why it was difficult to obtain an explicit formula for pricing options under stochastic volatility. Thanks alot.

Comment: How about you try doing it from scratch and then let us know?

Comment: Look at the Heston model and try to solve the resulting pricing PDE or attempt to compute the integral of the characteristic function in closed form. The dynamics of the stock price process are just sufficiently complicated such that explicit solutions do not exist anymore. Also, recall that the BS solution is technically not in closed form but requires the evaluation of the integral $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^d \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)\mathrm{d}x$. It just happens that this integral is very easy to approximate.

Comment: hi..thanks so much for the assistance everyone.